# High symmetry points and x-coordinates

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, symmetry, conductivity

Is it possible to work out the x-coordinates related to high symmetry points?
The software I'm using doesn't provide me with that, so I was wondering if there is a way to manually figure it out, as I would like to add high symmetry point labels to an electronic band structure plot.

I found a similar question: https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2016-June/035548.html but I don't quite understand whats happening in the equation, if someone could please explain it that would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It would help is you gave an example, a molecule or crystal ? Generally I would say 'yes' it is possible.